# Dynamic Drop Down that changes Text Box value issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, I am going to try to ask this clearly as I can.

I am creating a drop-down menu that will upon selection of an option show:

- Shipping Total dynamically update for User Experience
- Change the 'value="CHANGETHISINFORMATION"' value in the textbox dynamically

Here is where my code is at:

```
// Pre populated array of data
var myData = new Array();
        myData[''] = '';
        myData['Light Oak 6" x 6" Set|65.05|0606'] = '$50.00';

var setTotal = new Array();
        setTotal[''] = '';
        setTotal['Light Oak 6" x 6" Set|65.05|0606'] = '15.00';

document.setSelect.selector.onchange = updateText;

function updateText() {
    var obj_sel = document.setSelect.selector;
    var shipTot = document.setSelect.shippingTotal.value;
    var totTot = document.setSelect.setTotal.value;
        shipTot = myData[obj_sel.value];
        totTot = ("item-AI SWDO|" + (myData[obj_sel.value] + setTotal[obj_sel.value]) + "|SoftWoods - Dark Oak|NA|0");
}​
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Dark Oak</h1>
<br>
<form action="/qs3/cart.php" method="get" onSubmit="return doOptionCheck(this);" id="setSelect" name="setSelect">
    <select id="selector" name="OPTION|1|AI SWDO">
        <option value="" selected>Choose your set size</option>
        <option value='Light Oak 6" x 6" Set|65.05|0606'>
            6' x 6' Set - $65.05
        </option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Shipping Estimate: <input type="text" value="" id="shippingTotal" name="shippingTotal" disabled>
    <br><br>
    QTY: <input type="text" name="item-AI SWDO|CHANGETHISINFORMATION|SoftWoods - Dark Oak|NA|0" id="setTotal" size="3" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart2" value="Add to Cart!">
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Now this cart is archaic to say the least. Perl with other script engines were used. So I am having to make due until we upgrade our site to a better cart.

I was able to originally* make the shipping box value physically change, it was only after I tried toying with the inner-value on the 'Qty:' box that made things stop working.

EDIT: Fixed my last sentence.

Comment: Good for you, making it work and all, but what is the question, and what is'nt working?

Comment: Note that the `Array()`s you are initializing are not actually being used as arrays (more like PHP arrays). JavaScript arrays expect incremental numeric indices only. Yours are actually appending object properties. Best to just declare them as objects to begin with `var myData = {};`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - +1, It looked so strange with those associative arrays (that don't exist in javascript) that I had to test it out, and it does seem to be working, but as you say, as objects -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbwYx/2/)

Comment: Apologies. I was able to originally* make it work. It was only after I started to toy with the QTY value that the code stopped working.

These arrays were borrowed from another posters code for dynamic drop down menus populating text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use datatable for this? http://www.datatables.net/ If I understand correctly, you want some element to update the total/shipping price?

Not sure why you want to change an element name field...